# How do I make the new row take the focus?

Tags: jqgrid

I need to know how to make a new row that is added to the end of the grid, take the focus, that is, be the "selected" one? I am not using pagination and $grid["scroll"] = true.
Once I add the row (in mysql), I update the grid with:

```
jQuery('#lstGrid').trigger('reloadGrid',[{jqgrid_page:1}]);
```

but the following code does not work.

```
setTimeout(function(){
$("#lstGrid").jqGrid('setSelection', new_row_id );
}, 500);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the requirement, I think that by default this conception will not work. Let me explain:

You add a row in the grid and after click the button you save it in the mysql database and then do reload the grid. This operation mean that the row is added and you get new portion of the data, but sorted in a way that it is not know where the new added row is.

If you really want to use this conception you should do appropriate sort, which will place the new added row at first position and then do the selection.

By the way in your code there is a error: the parameter **jqgrid_page:1** does not have sense, since it is not valid. The correct is page i.e :

```
jQuery('#lstGrid').trigger('reloadGrid',[{page:1}]);
```

but this will not help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tony for your help. I write here because I have the possibility to publish the code more clearly. I can't rate your answer yet because I don't have enough points yet. I have modified the code and with this I got what I need.

```
jQuery('#lstCertificacion').trigger('reloadGrid', [{page:5}]); 

setTimeout(function(){
 
    var ids = $("#lstCertificacion").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
       
    for (var z=0;z<ids.length;z++) {
        var row_id=ids[z];
        $("#lstCertificacion").jqGrid('setSelection', row_id );
    }
    
}, 200);
```